# graphical meaning of the "angle" between two 2x2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

**What's the graphical meaning of this question:**

find the angle between two matrices, $\cos \theta$, where:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 1 \\
    4 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
    5 & 0 \\
    1 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

**Book further explains:**

an inner product space exists between "n x m" matrices from a vector space, and it is given by the formula:

$$
<A, B> = tr(B^T A)
$$

$$
\cos \theta = \frac{<A,B>}{\|A\| \|B\|}
$$

$$
\|A\| = \sqrt{<A,A>}
$$

What does this mean graphically to find an angle between two 2x2 matrices.  I have a hard time visualizing what this would look like in the real world.  I can understand dot product between two vectors..its just arrows on a coordinate space, how would you draw a matrix on a coordinate space to find the angle between them?

Comment: There's nothing deep here.  You are supposed to think of an $m\times n$ matrix as a list of $mn$ numbers, a "vector" in $mn$-space.  The angle between two matrices is just the angle between the two corresponding vectors.

Comment: if the inner self-product of a square matrix is equal to the identity matrix, then the rows and columns form an orthonormal basis, ie., all rows or columns are both orthogonal to each other and normalized.